# How can I take a value from a document and add another value to it?

Tags: python

I have a Python program I'm writing that I would like to have track statistics given inputs. I'd like it to have two documents set up, and be able to refer to each. In each, there would be a value, let's say it's *x*. The program would be able to generate a number, and I'd like to be able to update the number in a given document by *adding* the generated number. Right now, my code would be as follows:

```
f1 = open("player1records.txt", "a+")

f1.write(str(int(P1wins) + int(f1.read)))
```

This, however, raises the following:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, 
not 'builtin_function_or_method'
```

How can I take that *x* and add another number to it, then update the document?

Comment: What's the type of `f1.read`?

Comment: typo: change `f1.read` to `f1.read()`

Comment: can you try out separately both the conversion to debug which one is causing the issue?. This is for sure will throw an error `f1.read` as read is a function and that cannot be converted to an `int` while `f1.read()` might if it is capturing a valid number

Answer (score 2):

don't forget to add the () to the end of a function to call it:

```
f1.write(str(int(P1wins) + int(f1.read())))  # not f1.read
```

Comment: Now I get this error:

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: @RyanCrank please tell me what is currently in player1records.txt in comments. it's possibly not a number, or the file is empty.

Comment: why not encapsulate in a `try except` block then?

Comment: @mad_ yes, you're right :). if the error reason is because the file is empty, a try-except is needed for the first run. I'm waiting for Ryan's response. if reason is empty file, I would edit the answer and add the missing exception handling. thanks

Comment: The file has the number 0 in it.

Comment: @RyanCrank so, is this code currently working? if not, you can solve it with a try-except or if-else block. if you're new to python, I can edit this code to implement the changes needed

Answer (score 0):

this sort of thing is difficult to do safely, one tends to end up with code that does:

```
from os import replace

def updateRecords(value, filename="player1records.txt"):
  try:
    with open(filename) as fd:
      prev = int(fd.read())
  except (FileNotFoundError, ValueError):
    prev = 0

  changed = prev + value

  # write to a temp file in case of failure while doing this
  tmpname = filename + '~'
  with open(tmpname, 'w') as fd:
    fd.write(str(changed))

  # perform atomic rename so we don't end up with a half written file
  replace(tmpname, filename)
```

all of this fiddling is why people tend to end up hiding this complexity behind a relational database.  Python includes a relatively nice [`SQLite`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) interface.  if everything was set up, you'd be able to do:

```
  with dbcon:
    dbcon.execute(
      "UPDATE player SET wins=wins + ? WHERE player_id = ?",
      (P1wins, 1))
```

and have the SQLite library take care of platform specific fiddly bits…